# Permanent Urls for facebook photos uploaded by user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, url

The questions is really straight forward. I have successfully retrieved photos uploaded by a user who authorized my fb app. I was thinking if i could store the url to my own database, and reference it from there instead of making a api request. The field am saving is the `source` field. Is this field permanent or does it change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its always better to keep the `id` of any facebook object(user-id, album-id, photo-id, post-id etc.). You can simply access to that object with-

```
http://facebook.com/<ID>
```

The `source` also will never change but why to keep it if id will serve the purpose. On browsing to the above url facebook redirects to the source itself.

Comment: what i want to do is `<img src="source">`. but when i go to `http://facebook.com/<PhotoID>` It redirects me to facebook. I want it to just display the photo. And also how sure are you that the `source` will never change?

Comment: Why will facebook do that? Transferring all the images to some other. No they will not.

Comment: They might do that to stop people from using facebook as a CDN! But if you have some info to support it, i would love to see it.